# script runs different from Cybermation than from command line

Tags: bash, sftp

I've got a bit of code failing in prod right now:

```
for filename in $WORKINGDIR/customer*dat
do
echo "-put $filename" >> $WORKINGDIR/$DWTFR
done;
```

which works just fine when I execute from the command line, on test the load file for sftp is populated with:

```
-put /home/batchrunner/customer_updates.dat
-put /home/batchrunner/customer_usr_all.dat
```

In production when executed from cybermation it instead is populated with:

```
-put /home/batchrunner/customer*dat
```

Which sftp pukes on.

Answer (score 0):

Try using find.

for filename in `find $WORKINGDIR -type f -name "customer*dat"`